# "Delete" isn't showing when swiping a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've scoured the other SO links related to this and none of the other solutions seem to work! I'd love if anyone has some insight! Below is the relevant code. What occurs when I swipe is the cell moves left, but the space where the delete button would be is empty.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog (@"%i",indexPath.row);
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    //Do other delete stuff
}


-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}
```

I thought that perhaps tableView:editingStyleForIndexPath wasn't getting called, but my NSLog shows that it is.

I've tried setting [self.tableView isEditing=YES] and that still results in an empty swipe.

Here is the code that sets up the tableview:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [receiptsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [receiptsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",[self getPathToDocumentsDirectory],self.nameOfRetailer,[receiptsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: How is your cell setup? Make sure any views you add to the cell are added to the cell's `contentView` and not directly to the cell.

Comment: Good point, rmaddy. I've added that code.

Answer (score -1):

Well, now I feel silly. The problem was the tableview extended past the parent view, so when I was swiping, I couldn't see the Delete button. I fixed the tableview's constraints and now it's working like a charm.